# To encounter a problem

Tags: meaning

Can encounter be used by facing or finding a solution of a problem?

For instance, can I say: Speeding can be encountered by placing speed bumps.

Or would counteracted be rather correct?

Comment: Um, I think you meant *speed bum**p**s*.

Comment: Consider: *speeding can be **countered** by ...*. Roughly-speaking: encounter = meet; counter = oppose; counteract = neutralise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*X encounters Y* means X is doing something and then Y appears to X, or X finds Y.

*Encounter X* does not mean to solve, but you can *X encounters a solution*, meaning X finds a solution.

You will then have to use additional words to describe that solution.

However *X counteracts Y* works - this means that Y works against X's effects.